ReactJS App Resources Not Loading Correctly When Accessed Via Link in Another App
I have two websites, both developed with ReactJS. Let's call them "homepage" and "samplecompanysite01".
I built the "homepage" site and copied its files into /opt/lampp/htdocs.
I built the "samplecompanysite01" site and copied its folder into /opt/lampp/htdocs/samples/samplecompanysite01/.

In the "homepage" site, there's a link defined as follows:
`
<a href="/samples/samplecompanysite01/index.html">
Open Sample Company Site
</a>
`
However, when I click this link, the "samplecompanysite01" site opens, but it doesn't load translations and other resources correctly. Upon inspecting the network requests, I noticed that the index.html file's status is 304 Not Modified.
It seems like the resources are not being loaded correctly when accessing the second site through the link. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it to ensure that all resources load correctly?
Additional Information:
Both sites are deployed using XAMPP on an Ubuntu server.
The "homepage" site is located at /opt/lampp/htdocs/.
The "samplecompanysite01" site is located at /opt/lampp/htdocs/samples/samplecompanysite01/.

Thanks in advance for your help!
This is the image showing the HTTP GET STATUS for index.html file of samplecompanysite01
